# How to concatenate 2 or more columns in beamSql

Tags: apache-beam

I'm trying to concatenate 2 columns using delimiter as "."
**code :**

```
PCollection<BeamRecord> first = apps.apply(BeamSql.query(
            "SELECT *,('CatLib' || 'ProdKey') AS CatLibKey from PCOLLECTION"));
```

How shall I specify delimiter between 2 columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say go for

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(CatLib, '') || '.' || COALESCE(ProdKey, '') AS CatLibKey,
    (any other columns here...)
FROM
    PCOLLECTION;
```

but in SQL there is no "Select everything but column X" or "Select everything else" so you'd have to write down every name of the column you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Impulse The Fox. 
I have modified my query to :

```
PCollection<BeamRecord> first = apps.apply(BeamSql.query(
            "SELECT Outlet, CatLib, ProdKey, Week, SalesComponent, DuetoValue, PrimaryCausalKey, CausalValue, ModelIteration, Published, (CatLib || '.' || ProdKey) AS CatLibKey from PCOLLECTION"));
```

and this worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem, it would be nice if you accept my answer :)